# Include particular header files in a cmake project with absolute paths

Tags: c++, cmake

to start with, I have the following repo structure.

```
root
|
|--- blocks
|     |
|     |---example
|         |
|         |---example.cpp
|         |---CMakeLists.txt
|
|--- interfaces
      |
      |--- types
            |
            |-- types1.h
            |-- types2.h
            |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

What I would like to do is to only include `types1.h` in the cmake target of `example.cpp`. And I would like to include `types1.h` such that I can include it in `example.cpp` using its path relative to root (i.e. `#include "interfaces/types/types1.h"`) and I don't want to use `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` since that would expose the whole repo to the target.

`target_include_directories` did not work since it only includes directories but not individual files and I don't want to include a whole directory and expose irrelevant headers in types folder to example.cpp or move `types1.h` to a dedicated subfolder.

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

My current solution is as below which gives `fatal error: interfaces/types/types1.h: No such file or directory` when I compile exampleblock target. (I eased the requirements for start and allowed `interface_types` target to include `types2.h` also even though `example.cpp` doesn't need it)

`blocks/example/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

add_library(exampleblock STATIC
    example.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(exampleblock INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/interfaces/types:interface_types
)
```

`interfaces/types/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

add_library(interface_types INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(interface_types INTERFACE .)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to hide `types2.h` from `example.cpp`?

Comment: I am not a cmake expert but I assumed it would make the build graph complicated and it is also cleaner to include only relevant files.

Comment: The files you are including are defined in `example.cpp`. There you write `#include <types1.h>`. You don't need to worry that the compiler could see the files if you do not include them. The build graph is solely dependent on whats written in your source files. Whats going to be compiled is specified in CMake and these are the `*.cpp` files

Comment: Then it is ambiguous which `types1.h` example.cpp is including, as there might be multiple files with same name (not ambiguous to the compiler maybe but to human).

Comment: How often does it happen in your repository that a header file has the same name? It can happen of course, but then the relative path should give away to which library the header file belongs. Also you cannot store a file with the same name in the same directory so that is not even possible

Comment: Not very likely but it would be more readable if the header was included with abs path. I added my CMakeLists.txt in the post. Let's say it is okay to include `types2.h` even though `example.cpp` doesn't need it still. Do you see why I am getting the  `no such file` error?

Comment: Simple (and preferred solution: simply move the header to it's own directory, e.g. `root/include/interfaces/types/types1.h` (note that usually you use on dir less). More complex and not recommended approach: Use `add_custom_command` to "generate" the header in a appropriate subdir in the build dir by simply copying it over. You need to make sure the targets using the file depend on it. You can the dir via `target_include_directories` as in the first alternative...

Comment: I think you (kaanyilmaz) are trying to simplify a project architecture doing things unconventionnal (include with a full path, trying to hide a header that doesn't need to be hidden). The result is you will have an even more complex CMakeLists.txt to understand, you do the exact opposite from your original goal... Don't try to include the full path in your header please, that's a wrong idea. (Check different project to see if other developers are doing this as well)

Comment: The project I have been referring to is actually a bazel project and I am migrating it to cmake due to third parties mostly supporting cmake but not bazel. With bazel, it was easy to achieve what I want. I agree with Martin and fabian that, with cmake, this architecture is going make cmake too complicated that changing the repo structure becomes justifiable. Thanks for feedback!